# Any tips for keeping bluetooth apps running in background on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm building an iPhone app which communicates with a BLE peripheral. I take a reading from the device and do some small computations 10 times a second. I am using the `bluetooth-central` declaration in info.plist.

The OS suspends the app at random times. Sometimes after a few hours, sometimes after a few minutes.

Any tips or tricks to keep it running?

Comment: You will need to opt-in to CBCentral state restoration (Described in the Core Bluetooth Programming Guide) and ensure that your peripheral is sending updates via notify; you cannot poll for updated data.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the tip. So are you saying the best I can hope for is to be able to restore the state if it gets shut down?

Comment: Generally iOS will try and keep apps alive if they are continuing to perform work in the background, but the only app that is *guaranteed* to be running is the app that user is currently using in the foreground. You should opt in to state restoration if you want your app to be relaunched when it is (almost inevitably) terminated.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11. You put me on the right track. I have a follow-up question to your comment. So say we only ever have one CBCentralManager and we set the restoration identifier when we instantiate it, and we implement the willRestoreState method. And the app gets terminated. Then the peripheral sends an update via notify. And the app gets relaunched in the background. Do we have to manually reinstantiate the CBCentralManager in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method? And restore the rest of the application state from the dict and saved data? Or does the app just pick up where it left off?

Comment: Yes, you need to check for state restoration in the options passed to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and re-instate your CBCentralManager and the rest of your application state; it is a fresh launch of your app.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this by enabling following bluetooth feature from capabilities.

1. External accessory communication
2. Uses Bluetooth LE Accessories
3. Acts as a Bluetooth LE Accessory

[image]

Comment: enabling from here, what will be next step ??

Comment: Adding one of these is necessary but it's not enough. It can still be shut down.

Comment: Please follow for more details, Apple official documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4